# Is the connection id in apigateway websocket unique?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS websocket api gateway and I can get a connection id from the request context. The connection id is a websocket id which I need to save in our database for connection management.

What I am not sure is whether the connection id is unique? Is it possible to get a duplicate connection id when my application is running for a few years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes the `connectionId` value provided in the `context` object is unique,

from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-mapping-template-reference.html)

> **API Gateway WebSocket API mapping template reference**
>
> $context.connectionId -> A unique ID for the connection that can be used to make a callback to the client.

Comment: what I am not sure is whether it is unique for history connections. I am planning to save it to database as primary key and don't want to get duplicate error.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao unique is unique, you don't need to worry about collision

I will say using a unique but ultimately very temporary value such as the connectionId as a primary key for years with no regular pruning sounds like a waste of storage